# Enabling GRASS in Processing Toolbox of QGIS 3.28.2.0

Tags: qgis-3, grass-gis, installation, windows-10, toolbox

I installed QGIS 3.28.2.0 (Release candidate) via Network installer on Windows 10.

I am missing GRASS in the Processing Toolbox. How to enable this?

GRASS 7.8 is installed (There is no separate start link "QGIS with GRASS" like it was there in older QGIS-Versions) and trying to enable additional providers in the toolbox does not find GRASS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok , I found it:

enable GRASS and GRASS Provider Plugin via the Plugin Menu

UPDATE: for the Processing Toolbox you only need the GRASS Provider Plugin